# Is ascii character 255 an invisible character or space?

Tags: c++, ascii

I am writing some code to print overlapping ASCII character objects and I want some to be invisible instead of the typical " " white space character. Would this solve it?

```
cout << char(255);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "ASCII 255" - ASCII is a 7 bit character set. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: ASCII is a 7 bit encoding and so has values in the range 0..127

Comment: Oh okay. I think I was talking about a decimal character instead.

Comment: What is a decimal character?

Comment: decimal value. like a hex value

Comment: Isn't 255 assigned to an extended ascii code for nbsp? Sorry if I confused anyone. Just trying to figure this out. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Could you give a visual sample of the output you are trying to achieve? Because I'm having a hard time understanding how a space is different from an invisible character.

Comment: @Dljcali If, by "extended ASCII" code, you are referring to ISO-8859, then no - `nbsp` is always at `0xA0` (160 decimal). 255 depends on the ISO-8859 variant, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859

Comment: well here is a snap shot of it. I am trying to move the cursor instead of create a space if that makes any sense. https://scontent-a-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/1523874_10100125388114783_706274088_o.jpg

Comment: Found my answer. It is not a white space as I was wondering. "non-breaking spaces are not merged with neighboring whitespace characters, and can therefore be used by an author to insert additional visible space in the formatted text. For example, in HTML, non-breaking spaces may be used in conjunction with a fixed-width font to create tabular alignment". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: I think that before you go any futher you need to learn the basics of character encoding, because unless you do you are going to store up a world of pain for some point in the future

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe for you older peoples, but for a long time now ASCII has included all 8 bits. From the link you posted: "...In most cases these developed as true extensions of ASCII, leaving the original character-mapping intact, but adding additional character definitions after the first 128 (i.e., 7-bit) characters." Nowadays, they're referred to as "variants" of ASCII but I have never seen anyone use 7 bit ASCII in recent years; now it's either 8 bit ASCII or Unicode.

Comment: @Andrew: No, ASCII has never included 8 bits. Wide-spread ignorance and imprecision doesn't change technical fact. That's why, for example, asking for the ASCII-encoded representation of `"\u00a0"` returns a byte array with containing 0x3f (ASCII for '?' - used when the specified character cannot be represented) in both .NET and Java. I agree that ASCII shouldn't generally be used (and nor should 8-bit encodings - there are simply too many useful characters for that to be appropriate), but ASCII still means what it's always meant: a 7-bit encoding.

Comment: ASCII is whatever we define it to be, just as with other words, some of which have changed meaning over time. Some implementations use 7 bit ASCII, some use 8 bit ASCII. It's not ignorance, it's modification.

Comment: @Andrew: ASCII is not “whatever we define it to be”, and “ASCII” is not just a descriptive or common word; it is an abbreviation for the American National Standard Code for Information Interchange. The latest revision is [INCITS 4-1986 (R2017)](https://standards.incits.org/apps/group_public/project/details.php?project_id=1829), and it remains a seven-bit code with 128 characters.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  All words are whatever we define them to be, and by the way I will note that the title in the standard you linked is "7-Bit American National Standard Code for Information Interchange (7-Bit ASCII)", they actually had to clarify that it is 7 bit. I have coded numerous times over the years in prominent languages that referred to the 8-bits as ASCII. I've had this same problem before, with HTTP 1 and 2. Standards change, and their implementations also tend to differ from the standards.

Comment: This is like the equivalent of saying that one is not making a recipe because they used different spices or a different amount of ingredients than was specified in the recipe. Well, it depends on how you define it... It's more complicated than that because we're talking about standards here, yes, but if the implementations in wide use differ from the standards then what's the point of declaring that said details of the standard are "standard", other than just to refer to a document? It ultimately depends on who you ask and what they're thinking about... as do all words.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 255.
And no <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 255 is not the same as a space.

Here is a table of the characters values.

| Char | Dec | Hex | Oct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPACE | 32 | 20 | 40 |
| <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 255 | 160 | A0 | 240 |

I don't know much C++ but maybe it is

```
cout << char(160);
```

Comment: It is a unicode code point the correct way in c++ (x11) is to use a unicode literal pre (x11) you will need to manually write a file in some encoding that supports multibyte characters.  You might be able to use '\0240'  as that will correctly work for u8.  What you have done with char(160) will only work if the encoding of the document you are writing is u8.

Comment: alt-0160 will also let you type the non breaking space character

Answer (score 4):

In the most common extended 8-bit ASCII tables 255 is the 'ÿ' symbol (Latin small letter y with diaeresis).
The space character is decimal value 32.
So what you are searching for is probably:

```
cout << char(32);
```

Comment: To be precise, that would be the ISO-8859-x extensions such as ISO-8859-1 (which coincides with the first 255 Unicode code points)

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII character 255 is actually a non-breaking space, or NBSP! This is definitely way too late haha, but 255 can definitely be used as a blank space.

Comment: A non breaking space appears as a space but a page formatter which recognizes it and cares will not break a line at that space. A lot of text editors just put in space for alt-255. The alt-xyz is Code Page 437 from original IBM Dos For more on that page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437